# Versioning of iOS frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I'm learning about creating iOS frameworks. One thing I can't figure out is how to version them. In my framework Xcode project, there are 3 fields for versions:

- Target -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Current Library Version (default value: 1)
- Target -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Compatibility Version (default value: 1)
- Target -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Framework version (default value: A)

1) Which of these fields should I use?

2) How do I access those values in the project that uses my framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use frameworks on OS X, they are almost always loaded dynamically, and in that case you have control with the app loading them to specify what version you want. On iOS, with static linking, I cannot think of any real way to use the versioning system to select one or the other in a bundle.

Comment: Good point about static linking in iOS. How about at compile time? Can I require a specific minimal version of the framework in a project that uses it?

Comment: Normally I seem to just drag in a project to another project when I have a "framework". I guess if there are multiple .a files within it, you might be able to select one of them - I never tried.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/VersionInformation.html

Though It is OS X document, I think that it may be right versioning method because framework structures of iOS and OS X are same.

According to the above document,

**Major Version : Framework version**

- You must change the major version designator for your project. Build your framework and incorporate the new version into your existing framework directory structure.

**Minor Version( with public interface change ) : Compatibility Version**

- Increment your current version number and set your compatibility version number to match. Build your framework.

**Minor Version(with no public interface change ) : Current Library Version**

- Increment your current version number. Do not change the compatibility version number.